# How to use STARTTLS with the OpenPop.Net C# library

Tags: c#, pop3, starttls

I need to connect to a Pop3 Server at 110 and fetch mails in an ASP.Net application. During connection I got an error " The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format". From googling I came to know that the server is using explicit SSL (STARTTLS). Is there way i can set openPOP.net to use STARTTLS? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use STARTTLS with OpenPOP.NET, but you could easily do it with [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) like this:

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {
    client.Connect ("pop.host.com", 110, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

    client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```